# Search delimited textfile in 2D array

Tags: vb.net

I have delimited a text file and put it into a 2D array. Then, I have tried to find out if the array contains the product ID (entered in a textbox). However, the code I have used to try to search the array and show the name does not work.
The textfile says:
1, Frances
2, Emma

Here is my code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim filename As String
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        filename = "names.txt"

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnsearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnsearch.Click


        filename = "names.txt"
        FileOpen(1, filename, OpenMode.Input,,,)

        Dim lines() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("names.txt")
        Dim values(lines.Length - 1, 1) As String
        For i As Integer = 0 To lines.Length - 1
            Dim parts() As String = lines(i).Split(","c)
            values(i, 0) = parts(0)
            values(i, 1) = parts(1)
        Next

        Dim ID As String
        ID = txtidsearch.Text

        Dim line As String

        Do While Not EOF(1)
            line = LineInput(1)

            If values().Contains(ID) Then
                lblid.Text = line
                Application.DoEvents()
                GoTo line1
            ElseIf EOF(1) = True
                MsgBox("Not Found")

            End If
        Loop
line1:
        FileClose(1)

    End Sub
End Class
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is create a class to hold your people. It would make it easier in the long run.

First create a `Person` class:

```
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel
Public Class Person
   Public Key As String

   Public Sub New(ByVal id As Integer,
                  ByVal name As String,
                  ByVal form as String)

       _id = id
       _name = name
       _form = form

   End Sub

   Private _id As Integer
   Public ReadOnly Property Id() As Integer
       Get
           Return _id
       End Get

   End Property

   Private _name As String
   Public ReadOnly Property Name() As String
       Get
           Return _name
       End Get
   End Property

   Private _form As String
   Public ReadOnly Property Form() As String
       Get
           Return _form
       End Get
   End Property

   End Class
```

Now create a `People` class which will be a collection to hold each `Person`:

```
Public Class People
    Inherits KeyedCollection(Of String, Person)

    Protected Overrides Function GetKeyForItem(ByVal item As Person) As String
        Return item.Key
    End Function

End Class
```

I would then change this bit of code:

```
Dim values(lines.Length - 1, 1) As String
For i As Integer = 0 To lines.Length - 1
    Dim parts() As String = lines(i).Split(","c)
    values(i, 0) = parts(0)
    values(i, 1) = parts(1)
Next
```

To this:

```
Dim myPeople As New People
For i As Integer = 0 To lines.Length - 1
    Dim parts() As String = lines(i).Split(","c)
    myPeople.Add(New Person(parts(0), parts(1), parts(2)))
Next
```

Note that I am adding a new `Person` class to the `People` collection class.

And I would replace this code:

```
Dim line As String

Do While Not EOF(1)
    line = LineInput(1)

    If values().Contains(ID) Then
        lblid.Text = line
        Application.DoEvents()
        GoTo line1
    ElseIf EOF(1) = True
        MsgBox("Not Found")

    End If
Loop
line1:
```

With this:

```
Dim filteredLines = From people In myPeople
                    Where people.Id = ID
                    Select people

If filteredLines IsNot Nothing AndAlso filteredLines.Count = 1 Then
    Label1.Text = filteredLines(0).Name
End If
```

This last bit of code is [LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308959.aspx):

> General-purpose query facilities added to the .NET Framework apply to all sources of information, not just relational or XML data. This facility is called .NET Language-Integrated Query (LINQ).

Using LINQ we can query the `People` collection class like we would a table on a database using similar syntax. Here I am selecting all of the `People` where the `ID` matches. I then check to ensure that `filteredLines` actually has a `Person` before assigning the value.